# getting a different context variable when creating EmbeddedView

Tags: angular6

In this piece of code, I am creating an embedded view and am passing a context. The embedded views are image thumbnails

```
const thumbnailContext = new ThumbnailContext(new ImageContext(divId,
      buttonId,
      imgId,
      closeId,
      imageString, this.thumbnailContainerRef.length, null));
    // viewref is empty  now. It will contain reference of this created view (see below)
    console.log('uploading context ',thumbnailContext);
thumbnailTemplateViewRef = this.thumbnailContainerRef.createEmbeddedView(this.thumbnailTemplateRef, thumbnailContext);
```

The classes are defined as follows

```
export class ImageContext {
  constructor(public divId: string,
              public buttonId: string,
              public imgId: string,
              public closeId: string,
              public imgSrc: string,
              public index: number,
              public viewRefId: EmbeddedViewRef<ThumbnailContext>) {} //TODOM - not sure if the types are correct
}
export class ThumbnailContext {
  constructor(public context: ImageContext) {}
}
```

The console print is correct as per me

```
ThumbnailContext {context: ImageContext}
context: ImageContext
divId: "thumbnail-1"
buttonId: "thumbnail-button-1"
imgId: "img-1"
closeId: "close-button-1"
imgSrc: "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAjUA"
index: 0
viewRefId: null
```

The view gets embedded here

```
<ng-template #thumbnailTemplate let-context="context"> 
    <div id="{{context.divId}}"> 
      <img id="{{context.imgId}}" src="{{context.imgSrc}}"> 
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="{{context.closeId}}" (click)="this.deleteThumbnail(context)"></a> 
    </div>
  </ng-template>
```

The images get created correctly. But when I try to delete them using `deleteThumbnail` and pass the context back to it, I am getting an incorrect context

```
deleteThumbnail(thumbnailContext: ThumbnailContext) {
     console.log("delete thumbnail  clicked with context ",JSON.stringify(thumbnailContext));
    const index = thumbnailContext.context.index; //I get error Cannot read property 'index' of undefined here
  ..
}

delete thumbnail  clicked with context  {"divId":"thumbnail-1","buttonId":"thumbnail-button-1","imgId":"img-1","closeId":"close-button-1","imgSrc":"..."}
```

I think I should get an object with context object it in `{context:{"divId":"thumbnail-1","buttonId":"thumbnail-button-1","imgId":"img-1","closeId":"close-button-1","imgSrc":"}}`

My suspicion is that in `let-context="context"`, the context variable is getting mapped to the `context` property of the `Thumbnail` class. Is the correct?

```
export class ThumbnailContext {
  constructor(public context: ImageContext) {}
}
```

How can I make the passed context map to `ThumbnailContext`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My understanding about how `let-` directives work was incorrect. When I write `let-something="context"` then `context` is a key in the object passed to the template. The value of this key becomes available as `something` in the template.

Picking from some other answer from SO, there are two ways to pass context to a `ng-template`. Either assign value to Angular's `$implicit` or create a new `key` in an object and refer to that `key`
if you add a template

{{col}}

{{foo}}

If the object passed is {$implicit: 'World', bar: 'Svet'}; then `col` will be assigned the value `{world}` because it is assigned the `$implicit` value. `foo` is assigned value of bar i.e. `Svet` because `foo` is equal to the key `bar` of the passed object and `bar`'s value is `Svet`.

for `let-col` the context property `$implicit` is made available as `col` within the template for bindings i.e angular is creating an object `{col:'World'}` which makes the code equivalient to `let-col="col"`. So `col` maps to key `col` whose value is `world`.

So if I use `let-mycontext="context"` in the html then I need `context` property in the  object passed which is there in my case. I am passing object `ThumbnailContext` which has a key `context`

```
export class ThumbnailContext { constructor(public context: ImageContext) {} }
```

So `mycontext` inside template is actually `ImageContext` and it is local name in the template.

As I have `ImageContext` available in the template and I am passing it to `deleteThumbnail`, I had to also change `deleteThumbnail` `deleteThumbnail(thumbnailContext: ImageContext) {...`